# Как добавить коллекцию в другую коллекцию на Java?

Tags: java, java-ee

Задание: добавить элементы второй (vector `v2`) коллекции в первую (vector `v`) коллекцию после каждого слова

На `i=3` выдает ошибку(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 3), в чем может быть проблема?

```
int size = v.size() + v2.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size + 2; i++) {
    v.insertElementAt(v2.elementAt(i), i + 1);

    //v.add(i+1,v2.get(i));
    System.out.print(v.get(i) + " ");
}
```

RAW:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    Vector v = new Vector();
    Vector v2 = new Vector();
    String s = "";
    String s2 = "";
    try {
        System.out.println("Первое предложение:");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System. in , "CP1251"));
        s = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("Второе предложение:");
        BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System. in , "CP1251"));
        s2 = br2.readLine();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Ошибка в справочнике");


    }
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, " \t\n\r,.");
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        // Получаем слово и заносим в вектор
        v.add(st.nextToken());
    }
    System.out.println("");
    StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(s2, " \t\n\r,.");
    while (st2.hasMoreTokens()) {
        // Получаем слово и заносим в вектор
        v2.add(st2.nextToken());
    }
    System.out.println("Первая коллекция:");
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Элемент=" + v.get(i));
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Вторая коллекция:");
    for (int i = 0; i < v2.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Элемент=" + v2.get(i));
    }

    int size = v.size() + v2.size();

    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size() + 1; i++) {
        v2.insertElementAt(v.elementAt(i), i + 1);
        //v2.add(i+1,v.get(i));
        System.out.print(v2.get(i) + " ");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, в условии задачи сказано, что нужно добавить элементы второго вектора в первый.

Во-вторых, в вашем цикле получается такое выражение `v.elementAt(v.size())`, что и вызывает ошибку о выходе за пределы массива. Метод size() возвращает количество элементов (счёт начинается от 1, а не от 0).

В-третьих, выводя на экран результат в этом же цикле, вы получите только половину вектора. А ведь он стал больше.

```
for(int i = 0; i < v2.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println("v.size = " + v.size() + " ; i = " + i);
    if (v.size() < 2 * i + 1) 
        v.addElement(v2.elementAt(i));
    else 
        v.insertElementAt(v2.elementAt(i), 2 * i + 1);
}

for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
    System.out.print(v.get(i) + " ");
}
```

**UPDATE**

Конечно же, стоит защититься от того, что элементов второго вектора может быть больше элементов первого. И тогда мы опять получили бы выход за пределы массива. Добавил проверку, что если кончился первый вектор, то будем добавлять остальные элементы второго вектора в конец первого.

Comment: вроде бы тут достаточно кода, чтобы локализовать ошибку.

Comment: 2 часа потратил на эту задачу так и не решил

Comment: Изменил ответ. Ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста.

Comment: огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Еще вариант:(но такой вектор лучше не использовать в реальных проектах)

```
for (int i = 0, j = 1;i < v2.size(); i++,j+=2) 
    v.insertElementAt(v2.elementAt(i), j);


System.out.println("");
System.out.println("Первая коллекция:");
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println("Элемент=" + v.get(i));
}
```